# Specify the DB Name Dynamically in a Query

Tags: sql

I have this Monster SQl Query that looks to fetch data from a Staging Database, do a join on the Destination Database and insert/update data on a destination Table.

A simplified format would be somehting like this

```
MERGE INTO SOURCEDB.SCHEMA.DESTIANTIONTABLE AS TARGET
USING (SELECT COLA, COLB, COLC FROM STAGEDB.SCHEMA.SOURCE A INNER JOIN SOURCEDB.Schema,TABLEA) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE--

WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT
```

Can i set the STAGING DB Name dynamically, the query is huge so i do not want to use the exec SQl syntax.
Any suggestions?

Comment: i was gonna suggest EXEC SQL until you poo-pood that idea :)

Comment: thanks for the edits - bluefeet. @Randy, the query as i said is huge i have about 60 columns and the names are long as well. so the exec sql mode will be cumbersome to maintain for the support group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use synonyms.

```
DROP SYNONYM syn_a;
CREATE SYNONYM a FOR STAGEDB.SCHEMA.SOURCE;
DROP SYNONYM syn_b;
CREATE SYNONYM b FOR STAGEDB.SCHEMA.TABLEA;
DROP SYNONYM syn_target;
CREATE SYNONYM target FOR SOURCEDB.SCHEMA.DESTINATIONTABLE;

MERGE INTO syn_target as TARGET
USING (SELECT COLA, COLB, COLC FROM syn_a as A INNER JOIN syn_b as B
) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE--

WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT
```

Comment: Thanks GreenLion, Synonym it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server doesn't like to substitute @variables for the database name, schema, or table, which is probably what you are after, so one way or the other you will need to go the dynamic sql route by using EXEC.

There isn't a problem executing very large sql statements in Sql Server 2005 and later when you use nvarchar(max) data type.  The limit is the lesser of 2Gb or server memory.

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
set @Sql = '
MERGE INTO SOURCEDB.SCHEMA.DESTIANTIONTABLE AS TARGET
USING (SELECT COLA, COLB, COLC FROM '+@StageDB+'.SCHEMA.SOURCE A INNER JOIN SOURCEDB.Schema,TABLEA) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE--

WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT ...
'
exec (@Sql)
```

Comment: the query as i said is huge i have about 60 columns and the names are long as well. so the exec sql mode will be cumbersome to maintain for the support group. –